# Локализация письма сброса пароля Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, уведомления

Системное сообщение `ResetPassword`, по стандарту находится в директории

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/auth/notifications/
```

```html
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ResetPassword extends Notification
{
 /**
  * The password reset token.
  *
  * @var string
  */
 public $token;

 /**
  * Create a notification instance.
  *
  * @param  string  $token
  * @return void
  */
 public function __construct($token)
 {
  $this->token = $token;
 }

 /**
  * Get the notification's channels.
  *
  * @param  mixed  $notifiable
  * @return array|string
  */
 public function via($notifiable)
 {
  return ['mail'];
 }

 /**
  * Build the mail representation of the notification.
  *
  * @param  mixed  $notifiable
  * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
  */
 public function toMail($notifiable)
 {
  return (new MailMessage)
   ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
   ->action('Reset Password', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)))
   ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
 }
}
```

Пытаюсь создать его локализованную копию, копировал во все возможные папки, типа app/notifications все равно приложение не видит его и использует стандартный класс. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 5):

Нашел на англ стаке [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574001/how-to-change-reset-password-email-subject-in-laravel) и понял свою ошибку

Краткое содержание, как сделать свою версию стандартного системного сообщения Laravel:

1) Генерируем свой собственный шаблон:  `php artisan
    make:notification ResetPassword`, он появится в директории
    `app\Notifications`;

2) В полученном файле в `return (new MailMessage)` добавляем тему письма `->subject()`, чтобы отправка выглядела так:

```html
 public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Тема')
            ->line('Тело письма часть 1')
            ->action('Название кнопки', url('password/reset', $this->token))
            ->line('Тело письма часть 2');
    }
```

3) В `app\User.php` переопределяем стандартный метод `sendPasswordResetNotification()`

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

...
//встраиваем ваш обработчик
use App\Notifications\ResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    ...

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        // Добавляем свой класс.
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

Поле этих манипуляций на почту будет приходить ваша версия уведомления.

Comment: В добавленном классе  ResetPassword определите свойство $token:
protected $token;
   
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл более изящное решение для себя: установил пакет **caouecs/laravel-lang** , выполнил действия согласно инструкции и весь Laravel, включая письма стал на русском.