# Настройка отправки электронной почты для сброса пароля в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

я создал локализованную копию `ResetPassword.php`, переопределил метод `sendPasswordResetNotification()`  в `app\user`. Общем все сделал по правилу( я так думаю))). Все норм, письмо в mail отправляет но только одно проблема есть. Срок действия этой ссылки не истекает . по умолчанию там 60 минут, после этого ссылка должен уничтожатся . Но этого не происходит. ниже мой код буду благодарен любой помощи.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class mytelresetpassword extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        //
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * The callback that should be used to build the mail message.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $toMailCallback;

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
        }

   $time = ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')];
   $time = $time['count'];

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Şifrənin Dəyişdirilməsi')
                    ->line('Hesabınızdan şifrə yeniləmə tələbi aldığımız üçün bu mail sizə göndərilib.')
                    ->action('Şifrəni Yenilə', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', ['token' => $this->token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()], false)))
                    ->line('Bu link '.$time.' dəqiqə müddətində keçərlidir, bu müddət bitdikdən sonra deaktiv olunacaq!')
                    ->line('Şifrə dəyişməyi tələb etməmişsinizsə,   "Şifrəni Yenilə"  düyməsini klikləməyə ehtiyac  yoxdur.');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }
}
```

`app\user`

```
 public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new mytelresetpassword($token));
    }
```

Comment: В документации говорится, что за время отвечает параметр `expire` в файле `config/auth.php`.

Comment: да  $time = ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')];

Comment: `php artisan config:cache`? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/797379/256824

Comment: не помогла команда `php artisan config:cache` и на той ссылке нету ответа на мой вопрос((

Comment: Ссылка из БД уничтожается, если пароль успешно сброшен, то есть задан новый. Выставьте `expire` одну минуту, очистите кэш `php artisan config:clear`, попробуйте через минуту сбросить пароль: под полем мыла на втором экране будет ошибка после той страницы, на которую вы из почты перешли.